# How do I install Bulma in Angular?

Tags: angular, bulma

I am getting an error, visible via the browser inspector after installing Bulma

I have angular-10.

The steps I took are

- npm -i bulma. The bulma directory is in node_modules/bulma
- npm i -D @creativebulma/bulma-collapsible
- Load javascript in *angular.json* as

  ```
  "styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
          "./node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
  ],
  ```
- Load the css in a component css file

  ```
  @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
  @import '~bulma/css/bulma.css';
  ```

The error message via the console is

```
 Could not load content for http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You load the bulma.css multiple time, once at `angular.json` and again at `css` import.

The steps could be simply,

1. Create new Angular application by
   `ng new angular-bulma`
2. Add bulma to the project by `npm install bulma`
3. Update the `angular.json` for bulma css by

   ```
    "styles": [
         "src/styles.scss",
         "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
    ],
   ```

Comment: Yes. The trick is testing with a basic section class="hero" and see that the css is being applied

Answer (score 7):

Do not do the following:

```
 "styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
 ],
```

as this will override the changes you make in the src/style.scss. Instead do this:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss"
 ]
```

and in the src/styles.scss file add your imports at the very end of the file.
Like:

```
@charset "utf-8";

$menu-item-color: red;
$text: red;
$menu-item-radius: red;
$radius-small: red;
$menu-item-hover-color: red;
$text-strong: red;
$menu-item-hover-background-color: red;
$background: red;
$menu-item-active-color: red;
$link-invert: red;
$menu-item-active-background-color: red;
$link: red;
$menu-list-border-left: red;
$menu-list-line-height: red;
$menu-list-link-padding: red;
$menu-nested-list-margin: red;
$menu-nested-list-padding-left: red;
$menu-label-color: red;
$text-light: red;
$menu-label-font-size: red;
$menu-label-letter-spacing: red;
$menu-label-spacin: red;

@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
 ],
```

This does not work now. You can only add bulma or bootstrap to styles.css by `@import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';`